# Can rain cause the dirt on the roof?

Tags: roof, cleaning, shed, rain, cleanout

It's a terrace shed that has roof made of tin-can steel.

There are no trees or buildings higher than this.

I wonder how rain has brought this much dirt onto the top of my roof.

Should I clean this or this dirt is nothing to get bothered about ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Arizona sand storm

Comment: I see :) The place where I live don't have any sand storm and the land is clay. But wind can bring from elsewhere like from long distance. Cleaning the roof seems bit risky business.. Should I clean it  or would it cause some kind of ionization and the roof will get rusted .. .any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd be amazed how far sand can travel in the air.
I've on occasion seen my car looking like that after a particular wind/rain pattern. I'm in the UK, the sand came from the Sahara, well over 2,000 miles away.

[Explainer: how does Saharan sand end up in the UK?](https://theconversation.com/explainer-how-does-saharan-sand-end-up-in-the-uk-25236)

As to what to do about it - the next rain storm will probably wash it all off again. Unless you're particularly worried about the cosmetic appearance, leave it to the weather.

Comment: Thanks for the link

Comment: Welcome. . . :)

Comment: I mean, the Canadian wildfires earlier this year were bringing smoke pretty far south into the US.

Answer (score 1):

Splash from the ground. Pollen. Dust. Yes. (Where else do you think it came from? If someone was throwing sand on your roof, hopefully you'd notice...)

Comment: The roof is like 30 feet above the ground and I'm not sure if this is really sand or something like calcium or some mineral from rain ? may be I'm overthinking here. But I never expected to see this much on top of my roof. It's probably a year and it has seen just two monsoons so far.

Comment: Does this needs to be removed like it's gonna cause some rusting or degrading in future ?

Comment: It does look a lot like dust/pollen - so either industrial or plant-based, depending on your location. Not much you can do except hose it down periodically to clean it. But I wouldn't worry about it unless I had solar panels.

Comment: I can hose it down and again it's not necessary. But may be i will do this when I'm free